# writing large number of constraints in AMPL

Tags: ampl

I am trying to solve small instances of TSP in AMPL. But the subtour elimination constraints are too many even for a small instance. What would be a efficient way to write these constraints in AMPL. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the usual formulation of a set of subtour elimination constraints in AMPL

```
subj to SubtourElim {k in SS diff {0,2**n-1}}:
   sum {i in POW[k], j in S diff POW[k]: (i,j) in LINKS} X[i,j] +
   sum {i in POW[k], j in S diff POW[k]: (j,i) in LINKS} X[j,i] >= 2;
```

taken from http://ampl.com/FAQ/tsp.mod.

Since the number of constraints grows exponentially with `n`, instead of adding all of them in advance you can add them dynamically in an AMPL script as described [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ampl/mVsFg4mAI1c/ZdfRHHRijfUJ).